# Backbone maintaining state

Tags: backbone.js, state, singlepage

I am developing a JavaScript heavy single page app with Backbone.js. The goal is as follows;

- The user starts with a set of multiselect boxes which are populated with filter elements to query a set of resources. These multiselect boxes are dependent of eachother. Furthermore, the elements in the multiselects are queried from the server and depend on the user that is logged in, in other words they depend on the resources that are associated with the user that is logged in.
- The user fills out the multiselect boxes and presses a "filter" button. When this is pressed a collection is fetched, thereby using a set of query parameters (multiple array values) to get the set that reflects the filter elements.
- When the collection is fetched the view with the resources appear. This view has multiple subviews, and it must be possible to drill down on specific resources while maintaining state (the collection that is fetched as a result of the query parameters)

How to maintain state in a Backbone app in such a use case? I've looked through many examples but all are to simple to be useful.

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand which is the issue you are trying to solve here.

Comment: It might help if you have a concrete example illustrating your problem to save us the effort of visualizing the app. As for saving state, any time you have a model instance with attribute data, it is part of the state of the application. To persist this state, you'd be syncing with your server and probably saving your models in some DB. To get back to a certain state, you'd probably have an authentication system which can identify who is logged in and what models they are associated with.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to backbone.js and trying to develop a single-page app using Backbone.js. In my limited understanding of backbone.js documentation, I did not come across a better way of maintaining state using backbone.js core. However, in the past, I have worked with jStorage: http://www.jstorage.info/ , a simple wrapper plugin for Prototype, MooTools and jQuery to cache data (string, numbers, objects, even XML nodes) on browser side. It is simple to integrate and get started. In my app, I am going to use this for the time being... I thought this could be shared...hence I mention it here when I came across this question... I hope this would be of some help